# Ajax + PHP - Sending A Custom Value via Ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is in regards to using Google Charts.

I'm currently in the process of setting up a few line charts using Google Charts. The data being used to create these charts is being loaded from a MySQL database via a front end Ajax call to a PHP script to grab the data.

At current I have it set up, and working, to get the data and display it correctly as long as I am manually placing the required data in the PHP script, e.g:

```
    $keyword = "Test";
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE keywords = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $keyword);
```

So as seen in the example above, I'm telling the script to use the keyword of "Test".
However, I want to make it a dynamic call due to the fact I need to generate and display a few different charts, all of which containing separate information.

In order to achieve this I am currently setting a parameter in the URL based on the current page that is loaded, e.g:
        www.mywebsite.com/chart.php?id=mykeyword

No I can obviously grab that "ID" by using (this is placed above the Google Charts Ajax function:

```
    $id = $_GET["id"];
```

My issue here is that I've got no idea on how to send the custom data, the ID, through the ajax call. I've tried a few ways but I can't seem to get it to send through to the PHP function.

This is the Google Charts ajax:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "controller.php",
    dataType:"json",
    async: false
    }).responseText;


    jsonData = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + jsonData + ")"));
    var containerId = "chart_div"; 
    try {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document
    .getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 900, height: 220, vAxis: {maxValue: 10}});
    } catch (err) {
    alert( err.message );           
   }
   }
   </script>
```

The Ajax call send the data to a controller that looks like this:

```
    public function dataController() {  

        $update = new Chart($db);

        $update->keywordChart();
```

Now, I know that obviously I need to add the $id as a callback so that it can be sent to the PHP function e.g:

```
    dataController($id)
```

My problem Is, I can't seem to get the $id to actually send through the ajax call.

So, what would be the best way to have the URL ID to get included inside of that Google Charts Ajax call so that it also gets sent to the controller.php file?

I assume I need to somehow add it into here somewhere:

```
        function drawChart() {
          var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "controller.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose from these two :

```
 url: "controller.php?id=" + id ,
```

OR  :

```
      url: "controller.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: id},
```

Comment: That makes sense, I've given it a try however how do I then access that inside of PHP? I assume that will place the ID inside of a variable as $id?

Comment: Yes. Just assign the value to a variable id in JavaScript and pass it like this and you are sorted. May be pass the variable in function call : function drawChart(id)